# Flutter Installation: OS Error: Access is denied, errno=5

Tags: flutter

I tried installing flutter by following the steps at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install , but kept running into the following error when inputting flutter in to Command Prompt:

> Unhandled exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
> 'C:\Users\matt\AppData\Roaming.flutter_tool_state' (OS Error: Access
> is denied. , errno = 5) #0 _File.throwIfError
> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:645:7) #1 _File.openSync
> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:489:5) #2 _File.writeAsBytesSync
> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:614:31) #3 _File.writeAsStringSync
> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:638:5) #4 ForwardingFile.writeAsStringSync
> (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:154:16) #5
> ErrorHandlingFile.writeAsStringSync.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:137:22)
> #6 ErrorHandlingFile._runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:163:16)
> #7 ErrorHandlingFile.writeAsStringSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:136:5)
> #8 Config._flushValues (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:86:11) #9 Config.setValue
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:75:5) #10
> _DefaultPersistentToolState.isRunningOnBot= (package:flutter_tools/src/persistent_tool_state.dart:120:45) #11
> BotDetector.isRunningOnBot
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/bot_detector.dart:46:33)  #12 isRunningOnBot
> (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:98:48) #13
> runInContext.runnerWrapper
> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:63:34) #14
> AppContext.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29) #15 _rootRun
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13) #16 _CustomZone.run
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19) #17 _runZoned
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10) #18 runZoned
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1539:10) #19 AppContext.run
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18) #20 runInContext
> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:67:24) #21 run
> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:48:10) #22 main
> (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:69:9) #23 main
> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
> #24 _startIsolate. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32) #25
> _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: May you disable Windows Security AV. It might not let the flutter installation to access some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)

Error 5: Access denied is a known issue on Windows 10. This error prevents you from installing software on your computer and accessing or modifying certain files.

The reason for this issue is the non-availability of the permissions. Windows 10 will prevent you from installing if you don’t have the Administrator privileges or if your account is not the administrator account.

[How to Fix Error 5 Access Denied?](https://appuals.com/fix-error-5-access-denied-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me disabling the "Controlled folder access" option in Windows Defender

[image]